# Updating an application on Windows CE 6

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I have developed an application for Windows CE written in C#. It works very well, but now I want to update the application. It is an application which is for handheld scanners (Datalogic Memor X3).

Because there are already some devices which are already used, I have to update them via WLAN.

I have already compiled a new cab file, which is located on our webserver and I changed the app look for a new device on that server - if so, download the cab file and run this function:

```
public void installFile(string cabFile)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Process proc = new Process();

        info.FileName = @"\windows\wceload.exe";
        info.Arguments = @"\" + cabFile;

        proc.StartInfo = info;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

But every time on my test-device the installer comes up - I can say where to install the cab file and then the installation fails because of open dll files (datalogic.dll).

In the Microsoft documentation it says, that wceload.exe will kill the current process, uninstall it and reinstall the cab file - for Windows Mobile - but I have Windows CE 6.

How can I kill the process and update my app, without making a second "updater" program, which is called?

Comment: there is a silent flag

Comment: Which one do you mean?